# Leaftlet.JS/CartoDB.JS API Map not working on IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, leaflet, cartodb

I have a map that was built using Leaflet.JS and CartoDB.JS API. The map works beautifully on Google Chrome and Safari, but the pins do not show up on IE, and on FireFox, the pins show up but you can't click them.

Here is the URL: http://booktravelbound.net/experienceamerica/

I am not an expert developer and I had this job done by a contractor. Would someone be able to help? First time on Stack Overflow, so please forgive me!

Here is the javascript code:

```
var InteractiveMap = L.Class.extend({

options: {
    'redIcon' : L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'img/leaflet-color-markers/marker-icon-red.png',
        iconRetinaUrl: 'img/leaflet-color-markers/marker-2x-red.png',
        iconSize: [25, 41],
        iconAnchor: [12, 41],
        popupAnchor: [1, -34],
        shadowSize: [41, 41]
        //shadowUrl: 'my-icon-shadow.png',
       //shadowRetinaUrl: 'my-icon-shadow@2x.png',           
        //shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
    }),
    'greyIcon' : L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'img/leaflet-color-markers/marker-icon-grey.png',
        iconRetinaUrl: 'img/leaflet-color-markers/marker-icon-2x-grey.png',
        iconSize: [25, 41],
        iconAnchor: [12, 41],
        popupAnchor: [1, -34],
        shadowSize: [41, 41]
        //shadowUrl: 'my-icon-shadow.png',
        //shadowRetinaUrl: 'my-icon-shadow@2x.png',           
        //shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
    })
},

initialize: function(options) {       
    L.setOptions(this, options);
    if (null != this.options.cartoDbOptions) {
        this.initMapAsCartoDbViz();
    } else {
        this.initMapInUsualWay();
    }
},

initMapInUsualWay: function() {
    this._map = L.map(this.options.mapDivId, this.options.mapOptions);

    this.initBaseMapLayers();

    L.control.scale( { position : 'bottomright' } ).addTo(this._map);
    this.completeInit();
},

initMapAsCartoDbViz: function() {
    var _interactiveMap = this;
    cartodb.createVis(this.options.mapDivId, this.options.cartoDbOptions.vizURL,
        L.extend({
            center_lat: this.options.mapOptions.center.lat,
            center_lon: this.options.mapOptions.center.lng,
            zoom: this.options.mapOptions.zoom
        }, this.options.cartoDbOptions.vizOptions)
    )
    .done(function (vis, layers) {
        // layer 0 is the base layer, layer 1 is cartodb layer
        // setInteraction is disabled by default
        _interactiveMap._map = vis.getNativeMap();
        _interactiveMap.completeInit();
    })
    .error(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        _interactiveMap.initMapInUsualWay();
    });
},

initBaseMapLayers: function() {
    var baseMapLayerDescription = [
        { 'id' :"Carto", 'name' : 'Carto', 'default' : 'true',
                init : function() {
                    var layer = L.tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                        maxZoom: 18, attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy;<a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>'
                    });
                    return layer;
                }
        }
    ];
    this._baseMaps = {};       
    for (i=0, arrLen = baseMapLayerDescription.length; i < arrLen; i++) {    
        var tileLayer = baseMapLayerDescription[i].init();           
        this._baseMaps[baseMapLayerDescription[i].name] = tileLayer;
        if (baseMapLayerDescription[i].default) {
            tileLayer.addTo(this._map);
        }
    }
},

completeInit: function() {
    this.initCustomControlsOnMap();
    this._getJSON(this.options.dataUrl, this.addJsonToMap, this);
    this.initSideBar();
},

initCustomControlsOnMap: function() {
    //controlLayers = L.control.layers(this._baseMaps, this._overlayLayers);
    //controlLayers.addTo(this._map);
},

initSideBar: function() {
    this._sideMenuTemplate = document.getElementById('sideMenuTemplate').innerText;
    Mustache.parse(this._sideMenuTemplate);

    this._sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar', {
        closeButton: true,
        position: 'right'
    });
    this._map.addControl(this._sidebar);
},

addJsonToMap: function(data) {
    var lineLatLngs = [];
    for (var i = 0, arrLenght = data.length; i < arrLenght; i++) {
        var city = data[i],
            location = city.location.split(','),
            marker;
        if (city.active) {
            marker = L.marker(location, { icon : this.options.redIcon });
            lineLatLngs.push(marker.getLatLng());
            marker.cityDetails = city;
            marker.cityDetails.showHotels = !(null == city.hotels);
            marker.cityDetails.showTours = !(null == city.tours);
            marker.on('click', function () {
                //interactiveMap._sidebar.setContent('');
                interactiveMap._sidebar.getContainer().scrollTop = 0;
                var sideMenuContext = Mustache.render(interactiveMap._sideMenuTemplate, this.cityDetails);
                interactiveMap._sidebar.setContent(sideMenuContext);
                interactiveMap._sidebar.show();
            });
        } else {
            if ('0' === L.version.substr(0, 1)) { // v.0.7.x doesn't implemented marker.bindTooltip
                marker = L.marker(location, {
                    icon : this.options.greyIcon,
                    title : 'We haven\'t visited this city yet! Check back next week for new cities.'
                });
            } else {
                marker = L.marker(location, { icon : this.options.greyIcon });
                marker.bindTooltip('We haven\'t visited this city yet!<br/>Check back next week for new cities.');
            }
            marker.on('click', function () {
                interactiveMap._sidebar.hide();
            });
        }
        marker.addTo(this._map);
    }
    L.polyline(lineLatLngs, {dashArray: "5, 5"}).addTo(this._map);
},

_getJSON: function(url, callback, callbackContext) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    //xhr.responseType = 'json';
    //xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 304 && xhr.response) {
            //callback.call(callbackContext, xhr.response);
            callback.call(callbackContext, JSON.parse(xhr.response));
        } else {
            console.log('getJSON error', xhr);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
});


var interactiveMap = new InteractiveMap( {
    mapDivId : 'map',
    mapOptions : {
        center: L.latLng(37.19533058280065, -98.87695312500001),
        zoom: 4,
        zoomControl : false,
        dragging : false,
        doubleClickZoom : false,
        scrollWheelZoom : false
    },

    cartoDbOptions : {
        vizURL : 'http://telegul.carto.com/api/v2/viz/b167e126-38e5-11e7-ba84-0e3ebc282e83/viz.json', // <-- INSERT {YOUR vizjson_url}
        vizOptions : {
            shareable: false,
            title: false,
            description: false,
            search: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            cartodb_logo : false,
            tiles_loader: true,
            infowindow: false,
            layer_selector: false,           
            scrollwheel: false,
            layer_selector: false,
            legends: false
        }
    },
    dataUrl : 'data/ExperienceDomesticMap.json'
} );
```

Thank you!

Comment: Works fine for me.... check your multimedia settings on the Advanced tab of Internet Options... The first step in troubleshooting web browser issues is to test in noAddons mode. The web page has markup errors also. set up IE to record dev console messages. Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "always record developer console messages". Save changes.

Comment: Thanks @RobParsons! Useful tips. We actually found the bug and resolved the issue. Now, we're just facing another issue where IE isn't displaying the content correctly.

Comment: @CarmenCedeno if you found the issue, please consider marking the question as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a metatag to make the sidebar viewable on IE

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```